# How to break 32 bit value and assign it to three different data types.?

Tags: c

I have a

```
#define PROT_EN_DAT  0x140  
//(320 in decimal)
```

Its loaded into 64 bit value register(ex setup_data[39:8]=PROT_EN_DATA)

Now i want to put this value(0x140)into

```
 uint8_t    bRequest
 uint16_t   wValue
 uint16_t   wIndex
```

How can load the value so that i don't have to manually do it for other values again.
I think we can do with shift operators but don know how.

EDIT:Ya its related to USB. bRequest(8:15),wValue(16:31),wIndex(32:47) but setup_data is 64 bit value.I want to know how can i load proper values into the these fields.

For example say next time i am using #define PROT_EN2_REG     0x1D8.
and say setup_data[39:8]=PROT_EN2_DATA

Comment: You need to specify how you want to distribute the 32bit value (`PROT_EN_DAT`) over the 40bit range which your three variables give you.

Comment: Needs more information. You have a 32-bit value that you want to put into three variables which total 40 bits. Without an explanation it's not obvious which parts of the 32-bit value you want to go into each of the variables. Also, this: `setup_data[39:8]=PROT_EN_DATA` is not C.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that you're dealing with USB?

Comment: Looking at the variables you listed, I'd guess that the `setup_data` register can be looked at as three bit fields: `wIndex` (39:24), `wValue` (23:8), and `bRequest` (7:0).  "How can load the value so that i don't have to manually do it for other values again" is not clear English, and I can't be sure what you're asking.  Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: ya its related to USB.
bRequest(8:15),wValue(16:31),wIndex(32:47)
but setup_data is 32 bit value.I want to know how can i load proper values into the fields.

Comment: I haven't worked with USB, so I have no idea how PROT anything is supposed to map to those three fields, and whether or not setup_data has anything to do with it.  You're not specifying what `setup_data` is.  Your `setup_data[39:8]=PROT_EN_DATA` example makes it look like you're trying to assign `PROT_EN_DATA` (a 9 bit value) to a 32-bit field, which may or may not correspond to `wValue` and `wIndex`.  `setup_data` can't be a 32 bit value if it has a 39th bit.

Comment: @Mike:Sorry for some missing data.setup_data is a 64 bit value.There are other fields to to be filled which is taken care of.Other 24 bits are bRequestType,Length and Timeout value which are all 8 bits field.I wanted to know how can fit this 9 bit value in 3 different fields which sum up to 40 bits.(8+16+16)??

Comment: What (document, page, whatever) is telling you to put PROT_EN_DAT into those fields?

Comment: @Mike:I want to do a control transfer whose function has these three fields plus some extra.In hardware its been programmed as setup_data as 64 bit.I am writing an application for which i want to control transfer.So those 40 bits i want to fill with the #define value ie 0x140(12 bit).
      Now the problem is there are three fields of 8 ,16,16 bits and i want to fill in the values accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General read form:

```
aField = (aRegister >> kBitFieldLSBIndex) & ((1 << kBitFieldWidth) - 1)
```

General write form:

```
mask = ((1 << kBitFieldWidth) - 1) << kBitFieldLSBIndex;
aRegister = (aRegister & ~mask) | ((aField << kBitFieldLSBIndex) & mask);
```

where:

- `aRegister` is the value you read from the bit-field-packed register,
- `kBitFieldLSBIndex` is the index of the least significant bit of the bit field, and
- `kBitFieldWidth` is the width of the bit field, and
- `aField` is the value of the bit field

These are generalized, and some operations (such as bit-masking) may be unnecessary in your case.  Replace the `1` with `1L` if the register is larger than 32 bits.

EDIT: In your example case (setup_data[39:8]=PROT_EN_DATA):

Read:

```
aField = (setup_data >> 8) & ((1L << 32) - 1L)
```

Write:

```
#define PROT_EN_MASK = (((1L << 32) - 1L) << 8) // 0x0000000FFFFFFFF0
setup_data = (setup_data & ~PROT_EN_MASK) | ((PROT_EN_DATA << 8) & PROT_EN_MASK);
```

Comment: Note that `1 << kBitFieldWidth` has undefined behavior if `kBitFieldWidth` ≥ 31 (for 32-bit `int`). In practice your code will work almost everywhere, but still gives the wrong result when working with a register whose size is larger than `int`: `1 << kBitFieldWidth` should be `(type_of_aRegister)1 << kBitFieldWidth`, and `aField << kBitFieldLSBIndex` should be `(type_of_aRegister)aField << kBitFieldWidth`.

Comment: Yeah, I rely on the programmer to realize that they need to change the `1`s to `1L`s in the case of 64-bit registers, and to use unsigned storage types (as the question author did), but I'll update the answer anyway.